# If $R$ is a ring without divisors of $0$ (not necessarily commutative), is it true that for every $x\neq 0$, $xR=Rx$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R$ be a ring (not necessarily commutative), is it true that for every $x\neq 0$, $xR=Rx$?.

What I've tried so far was:

Let $y\in Rx$. Then $y=rx$ for every $r\neq 0,~r\in R$. Then $xrx\in xR$.

$\therefore yr\in xR.$

I'm not sure, but couldn't find a counterxample.

Comment: I don't follow your argument. Why would $rxr \in xR$?

Comment: Sorry, I edited it now.

Comment: Try taking $R$ to be the ring of two-by-two matrices over some field,  $x=\pmatrix{1&0\cr 0&0}$, and compare $xR$ and $Rx$?

Comment: How about the example of $\mathbb{Z}\langle a, b \rangle$ where $aR$ is the elements where every "monomial" with nonzero coefficient starts with $a$, whereas $Ra$ is instead the elements where every "monomial" with nonzero coefficient ends with $a$?  So for example, $ab \in aR$ but $ab \notin Ra$.

Comment: @paulgarrett The ring of matrices has zero divisors.

Comment: I am not following your reasoning—what do you mean by $y=rx$ for all $r\in R$ nonzero? Can you please post your definitions of the sets $xR$ and $Rx$?

Comment: @absolution-ever73, true, that ring of matrices has zero-divisors, but avoiding that didn't seem to be a requirement...?

Comment: $xR=\{y\in\mathbb{R}:~\exists r\text{ such that}y=xr\}$. $Rx$ is defined the same way.

Comment: Sorry, but what is $\mathbb{Z}\langle a,b\rangle$?

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}\langle a,b\rangle$ is like a polynomial ring, but the variables $a$ and $b$ are not assumed to commute with each other. So $ab\neq ba$.

Comment: Great, thank you all very much!!